# Iniciar uma função no click e parar a mesma ao clicar novamente?

Tags: javascript, html5

Inicialmente o background do circulo deve ser branco.Quando clicar no circulo executar em loop a função mudaCor e quando clicar novamente deixar o background do circulo branco parando a função mudaCor. Como fazer isso?

//o círculo se movimenta com as teclas a, w, s, d, mas não consigo executar os eventos acima.

segue o código completo:

```js
//----VARIÁVEIS----//
var dx;
var dy;
var px;
var py;
var vel;
var anima;
var ang;
var jog;
var skin;
var rotacao;
var tecla;
var tmp;
var tmpCor;
//-----------------//

function inicia(){
   dx = 0;
   dy = 0;
   px = 0;
   py = 0;
   vel = 5;
   ang = 0;
   rotacao = false;
   estadoCor = false;

   jog = document.getElementById("jog");
   skin = document.getElementById("skin");

   skin.addEventListener("click",giraPara);
   skin.addEventListener("click",mudaCor);
   document.addEventListener("keydown",teclaDw);
   document.addEventListener("keyup",teclaUp);

   tmp = setInterval(enterFrame,5);

   tmpCor = setInterval(mudaCor,1000);

}

//---FUNÇÕES DE ROTAÇÃO DO JOG---//

function gira(){
    if(ang>360){
         ang = 0;
    }
    ang+=8;
    jog.style.transform="rotate("+ang+"deg)";
    anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
}

function giraPara(){
   if(!rotacao){
      rotacao = true;
      anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
   }else if(rotacao){
      rotacao = false;
      cancelAnimationFrame(anima);
   }

}

//-------------------------------//

//---FUNÇÕES DE MOVIMENTO DO JOG---//

//Teclas --> a=65, w=87, d=68, s=83

function teclaDw(){
   tecla = event.keyCode;


   if(tecla==65){
      dx = -1;
   }else if(tecla==87){
      dy = -1;
   }else if(tecla==68){
      dx = 1;
   }else if(tecla==83){
      dy = 1;
   }
}

function teclaUp(){
   tecla = event.keyCode;

   if(tecla==65){
      dx = 0;
   }else if(tecla==87){
      dy = 0;
   }else if(tecla==68){
      dx = 0;
   }else if(tecla==83){
      dy = 0;
   }
}

function enterFrame(){
   px+= (dx*vel);
   py+= (dy*vel);

   jog.style.left = px + "px";
   jog.style.top = py + "px";
}

//----------------------------------//

//---FUNÇÃO DE CORES---//

function mudaCor(){
   var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
   var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
   var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);

   skin.style.backgroundColor= "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
}

window.addEventListener("load",inicia);
```

```css
#jog{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     background-color: #f00;
     display: flex;
}

#skin{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     border: 2px solid #000;
     background-color: #fff;
     border-radius: 50%;
     margin-left: -1px;
     margin-top: -2px;
     align-self: auto;
     cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="jog">
    <div id="skin"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que cancelar o `setInterval` `tmpCor` ao clicar (veja comentário no código). Você usa `clearInterval()` para isso:

```
clearInterval(tmpCor);
```

Agora o `tmpCor = setInterval(mudaCor,1000);` deve ser iniciado dentro da função `giraPara()` quando a variável `rotacao` for *false* e cancelado quando for *true*:

```
function giraPara(){
    if(!rotacao){
       // inicia o temporizador
       tmpCor = setInterval(mudaCor,1000);
        rotacao = true;
        anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
    }else if(rotacao){
       // cancela o temporizador
      clearInterval(tmpCor);
        rotacao = false;
        cancelAnimationFrame(anima);
    }

}
```

E para voltar para o fundo branco (`rgb(255, 255, 255)`), verifique se a variável `rotacao` é *true* ou *false* fazendo um ternário nesta linha dentro da função `mudaCor()`:

```
skin.style.backgroundColor= rotacao ?
    "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
                 ↑                        ↑
           cor aleatória                branco
```

Isso porque ao cancelar o `setInterval`, o temporizador não é cancelado de imediato, ainda irá chamar a função uma última vez dentro do tempo que ele possui.

Então ficaria assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Title </title>
        <style>
            #jog{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 1px solid #000;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                background-color: #f00;
                display: flex;
            }

            #skin{
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: 2px solid #000;
                background-color: #fff;
                border-radius: 50%;
                margin-left: -1px;
                margin-top: -2px;
                align-self: auto;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //----VARIÁVEIS----//
            var dx;
            var dy;
            var px;
            var py;
            var vel;
            var anima;
            var ang;
            var jog;
            var skin;
            var rotacao;
            var tecla;
            var tmp;
            var tmpCor;
            //-----------------//

            function inicia(){
                dx = 0;
                dy = 0;
                px = 0;
                py = 0;
                vel = 5;
                ang = 0;
                rotacao = false;
                estadoCor = false;

                jog = document.getElementById("jog");
                skin = document.getElementById("skin");

                skin.addEventListener("click",giraPara);
                skin.addEventListener("click",mudaCor);
                document.addEventListener("keydown",teclaDw);
                document.addEventListener("keyup",teclaUp);

                tmp = setInterval(enterFrame,5);

            }

            //---FUNÇÕES DE ROTAÇÃO DO JOG---//

            function gira(){
                if(ang>360){
                    ang = 0;
                }
                ang+=8;
                jog.style.transform="rotate("+ang+"deg)";
                anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
            }

            function giraPara(){
                if(!rotacao){
                   // inicia o temporizador
                   tmpCor = setInterval(mudaCor,1000);
                    rotacao = true;
                    anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
                }else{
                   // cancela o temporizador
                  clearInterval(tmpCor);
                    rotacao = false;
                    cancelAnimationFrame(anima);
                }

            }

            //-------------------------------//

            //---FUNÇÕES DE MOVIMENTO DO JOG---//

             //Teclas --> a=65, w=87, d=68, s=83

            function teclaDw(){
                tecla = event.keyCode;


                if(tecla==65){
                    dx = -1;
                }else if(tecla==87){
                    dy = -1;
                }else if(tecla==68){
                    dx = 1;
                }else if(tecla==83){
                    dy = 1;
                }
            }

            function teclaUp(){
                tecla = event.keyCode;

                if(tecla==65){
                    dx = 0;
                }else if(tecla==87){
                    dy = 0;
                }else if(tecla==68){
                    dx = 0;
                }else if(tecla==83){
                    dy = 0;
                }
            }

            function enterFrame(){
                px+= (dx*vel);
                py+= (dy*vel);

                jog.style.left = px + "px";
                jog.style.top = py + "px";
            }

            //----------------------------------//

            //---FUNÇÃO DE CORES---//

            function mudaCor(){
                    var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                    var g = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);
                    var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*255);

                     skin.style.backgroundColor= rotacao ? "rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")" : "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
                }




            window.addEventListener("load",inicia);


        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="jog">
            <div id="skin"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Vale observar que o `else if` na função `giraPara()` é redundante, pois se `rotacao` não for *false*, só pode ser *true*. Basta apenas um `else`:

```
function giraPara(){
    if(!rotacao){
       // inicia o temporizador
       tmpCor = setInterval(mudaCor,1000);
        rotacao = true;
        anima = requestAnimationFrame(gira);
    }else{
       // cancela o temporizador
      clearInterval(tmpCor);
        rotacao = false;
        cancelAnimationFrame(anima);
    }

}
```